# scanf stops working after first one [C]

Tags: c, struct, scanf

I am trying to have the user enter for the first, middle, and last name in my struct. The first scan works fine, any after that do not work. Here's my code so far

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

#include "contacts.h"
int main (void)
{
    // Declare variables here:

    struct Name names;
    char yesNo;

    // Display the title

    printf("Contact Management System\n");
    printf("-------------------------\n");

    // Contact Name Input:

    printf("Please enter the contact's first name: ");
    scanf ("%d", &names.firstName);
    printf("Do you want to enter a middle initial(s)? (y or n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &yesNo);
    while (yesNo ==  'y' || yesNo == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's middle initial(s): ");
        scanf(" %c%d", &names.middleInitial);
        yesNo = 'n';
    }
    printf("Please enter the contact's last name: ");
    scanf(" %c%d", &names.lastName);
```

Here's the struct in my header file

```
struct Name {
    char firstName[31];
    char middleInitial[7];
    char lastName[36];
};
```

When I enter more than one character the program ends, when I enter just one character, the program skips the second scanf. I had the program working beforehand but I realized I needed to use structs so I switched from int's to the struct, and I haven't been able to make it work this way.

Comment: `scanf ("%d", &names.firstName);`? Really? it should be `scanf ("%s", names.firstName);`

Comment: @Pablo In scanf(" %c%d", &names.middleInitial); are those two format specifiers valid if there's only one second argument? Does it just ignore the unused ones?

Comment: @Zebrafish no of course they are not, when I posted the comment, I hadn't finished the whole code yet. I addressed that in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `scanf` wrong.

```
scanf ("%d", &names.firstName);
```

`names.firstName` is a `char` array, but you are using `%d` which expects a
pointer to `int`, you are passing a pointer to an array. This is correct:

```
scanf("%30s", names.firstName);
```

Then you do

```
scanf(" %c%d", &names.middleInitial);
```

which has two errors: you are giving two conversion but passing only a on
pointer, and you are again passing the wrong pointer. Correct:

```
scanf("%6s", names.middleInitial);
```

and the same applies for `scanf(" %c%d", &names.lastName);`, the correct version

```
scanf("%35s", names.lastName);
```

In general, when using `scanf` with `%s`, you will have the problem that newline
and other strings are kept in the input buffer. This happens because `%s`
matches a sequence of non-white-space characters, so the newline (entered when
<kbd>ENTER</kbd> is pressed) will remain in the input buffer. Another example is
if the user enters two word separated by at least an empty space (like `Hello Word`),
`%s` would only read `Hello`. Subsequent calls of `scanf` may fail if they don't
anticipate this. That's why the best strategy is to clean the
buffer, use this function:

```
void clean_file_buffer(FILE *fp)
{
    int c;
    while((c = fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && c!=EOF);
}
```

And the you can use it like this:

```
printf("Please enter the contact's first name: ");
scanf ("%30s", names.firstName);
clean_file_buffer(stdin);
```

that takes care of left overs.

If you however want to have more control over the whole line, then you should
use `fgets` instead to read the whole line and then you can use `sscanf` to
parse it.

Comment: Nice answer.  Suggestion: make it clear that newline and other strings *remain* in the *stdio input* buffer.  They don't make it into any of the input variables in the program.  ("Are kept" and "the buffer" could be misread to imply that the characters do end up in one of the calling program's arrays.)

Comment: @SteveSummit thanks for the feedback, I expanded the paragraph, it's true in that context the word *buffer* could have been misinterpreted.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%s", names.firstName);
scanf(" %c", &yesNo);
scanf(" %s", names.middleInitial);
scanf(" %s", names.lastName);
```

or

```
scanf("%s", names.firstName);
getchar();
scanf("%c", &yesNo);
getchar();
scanf("%s", names.middleInitial);
getchar();
scanf("%s", names.lastName);
getchar();
```

and when yesNo question, if you typed over 1 character, first character will be into yesNo variable, and other chars will be into next input variable(names.middleInitial).
If you want to check the yesNo more carefully,
input yesNo as string. (but, buffer size check needed. buffer overflow.)

```
char yesNos[100];
scanf(" %s", &yesNos) ;
if ( yesNos[0]=='y' ) {...}
```